# Moving from Mercurial to Git and merging with custom changes

Tags: git, merge, mercurial, nopcommerce

I am having a problem with moving from Mercurial to Git and merging the last version of nopCommerce with my changes.

Here is what I did. I clonned the nopCommerce mercurial repository a long time ago (version 2.60 I think). Since then I made many changes to the platform and I merged them with newer versions of nopCommerce. The last merge I did was on version 3.10.

Now I see that nopCommerce started using Git, so I converted my mercurial repository to Git (following this guide: http://arr.gr/blog/2011/10/bitbucket-converting-hg-repositories-to-git/). But now, when I pull the nopCommerce changes (up to version 3.50), I get the following: "warning: no common commits", and ALL the commits are downloaded (not just the new ones, from 3.10 to 3.50), although I already have the commits up to version 3.10 in my repository. Basically, the nopCommerce commits up to version 3.10 are duplicated. I think this happens, because they have different commit numbers (when I converted my mercurial repository to Git, the commits got different commit numbers, and I see that the new nopCommerce Git repository also has different commit numbers from the old Mercurial repository).

The problem is that, when I merge nopCommerce v3.50 with the changes I made, and try to resolve the conflicts, the BASE file is empty, because Git does not see that they have a common ancestor. The LOCAL file has the commits from my repository as ancestors and the REMOTE file has the commits from the new Git repository as ancestors.

Do you have any idea of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably guessed right about the source of your problem. Git sees two completely separate histories and has no idea what to do with them. You can solve this using [`git replace`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html):

- Find the latest common ancestor between your history and theirs (=the latest commit that has a copy in both histories). Note the shas of these commits.
- Run `git replace **sha-in-your-history** **sha-in-theirs**`

have a look at the new `git log` and see whether the result is to your liking. If it is, you can make the changes permanent by running:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git replace -d **sha-in-your-history**
```

Afterwards you might want to clone the repo and delete the previous copy to actually remove “your” copy of history from your disk.